# Linker error in header file structure

Tags: c, header-files

I am having header file named data.h

```
#ifndef data_h
#define data_h

struct Student{
    int GPA;
    int coursesCount;
    float tuitionFees;
};
struct person{
    char firstName[11];
    char familyName[21];
    char telephone[11];
    int isStudent;
    struct Student student;
};
int maxCount=20;
struct person person[20];
#endif
```

In student.h I did something like this :

```
#ifndef __student__
#define __student__
#include <stdio.h>
#include "data.h"
void getStudentData(struct Student);
#endif
```

In student.c its like this :

```
#include "student.h"
void getStudentData(struct Student currentStudent){
     printf("Hi");
}
```

I get a Linker error when I ran it through another main.c file. which include all headers.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "student.h"
#include "data.h"
int main(){
    getStudentData(person[0].student);
}
```

What can be reason for this linker error? PLEASE HELP

Comment: What is the linker error?  How did you compile your program?

Comment: You forgot `extern` before your function declaration in `student.h`

Comment: @user3553031 Through xcode.

Comment: @Rostislav Why extern ?

Comment: @Rostislav Should be irrelevant. The C compiler can distinguish function declarations from function definitions, therefore extern is not required for functions.

Comment: @SebastianRiese I might be wrong. I'm definitely not a C expert. So I answered from a C++ stand point (barring not reading question carefully and missing the variables). And also that's why I removed the c++ tag from this question. So people like me don't go making (potentially) wrong comments.

Comment: @Rostislav: Your comment is equally wrong in c++.

Comment: @BillLynch Ah yes. Well, when the last time one used extern was about 5 years ago, one tends to forget even the simplest things. I'll leave the wrong comment in though to keep the comment thread readable.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring variables in header files is generally a bad idea. In your case, you are declaring two variables in your header file:

```
int maxCount=20;
struct person person[20];
```

Let's fix this by declaring them in a `*.c` file and creating references to them in the header file.

#### data.h

```
#ifndef data_h
#define data_h

struct Student{
    int GPA;
    int coursesCount;
    float tuitionFees;
};

struct person{
    char firstName[11];
    char familyName[21];
    char telephone[11];
    int isStudent;
    struct Student student;
};

extern int maxCount;
extern struct person person[20];

#endif
```

#### student.h

```
#ifndef student_h
#define student_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include "data.h"

void getStudentData(struct Student);

#endif
```

#### data.c

```
#include "data.h"
int maxcount = 20;
struct person person[20];
```

#### student.c

```
#include "student.h"
void getStudentData(struct Student currentStudent){
     printf("Hi");
}
```

#### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "data.h"
#include "student.h"

int main(){
    getStudentData(person[0].student);
}
```